# JS prototype : Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

[From the given MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance)

[image]

Why can't we just do the following code instead of the one given in picture , is there any difference between them?

```
Teacher = Object.create(Person);
```

Comment: @akash what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: Have you tried what you were suggesting? It doesn't work - can you reason why?

Comment: Think about the prototype chain of a `new Teacher` instance. How should that look?

Comment: Why asking a question meanwhile you could try it yourself and see the results?

Comment: I would suggest to have a read of this: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md#class-functions - and indeed the whole book. It's a very thorough explanation of what is in fact a very messy and much-misunderstood aspect of JS. Thankfully there is no need for it - firstly ES6 gives us the `class` keyword with much cleaner syntax for doing all this, but really I think it's best to stay away from trying to use class-based code at all in JS. (Because it's not a class-based language, even the ES6 `class` is just syntactic sugar.)

Comment: Maybe reading this could help?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: Thank you for selecting my answer, finally I made it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has two sub-questions.

1) Assigning `Teacher.prototype` vs `Teacher`:

```
let Teacher = function() { /* does something */ } // <-- the constructor

Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // <-- the constructor did NOT lost 
Teacher = Object.create(Person.prototype); // <-- the constructor lost
```

In the lower version you will lose the *constructor* of `Teacher` (of course if it existed). And in the upper one, you will overwrite only its prototype.

2) Assigning to `Person.prototype` vs `Person`:

```
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person); // Normally `Person` does not have any properties
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // But `Person.prototype` does.
```

In other words, one can very well add properties to Person, not to Prototype, but usually properties are added to `Person.prototype` so that they can be inherited by instances of `Person`.

```
Person.foo = function() {}
const person = new Person()
person.foo // undefined

// vs
Person.prototype.foo = function() {}
const person = new Person()
person.foo // its a function
```

Comment: Could you please clarify here how and why constructor was lost ?

Comment: Oh it's simple. Just like here: `let foo = 1; foo = 2;` we lose the `1` value.

Comment: My advice to you, if you are only beginning, is to practice. It is very hard to understand this javascript's part without practice. Just do your tasks and one day it will start clicking in your head finally.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.create` creates an object which cannot be callable. Even if you pass a function (constructor) as its argument, the object that is created by `Object.create` will not have the internal `[[Call]]` property, which is what makes function objects callable. It is not inheritable via the prototype chain.

So, in short, you need to define `Teacher` as a constructor (or using the `class` syntax, which still makes it a constructor function), which is something you cannot do with `Object.create`.

Comment: Could you please make it a bit more explanative , I'm new to JS and don't know much about it.

Comment: @HimanshuJotwani `Object.create(Person)` does not return a call- or construtable Object, so for `Teacher = Object.create(Person)` a  `new Teacher()`  throws a `TypeError: Teacher is not a constructor` and as of that it just does not work.

Comment: I executed the code and understood what you were saying ! but one more thing , how does Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype) makes it a constructor! Thanks.

Comment: @HimanshuJotwani, that on itself does not make `Teacher` a constructor. You must first define `Teacher` as a constructor function before you can adjust its `prototype` property like that. For instance `var Teacher = function() {}`... and then the `Teacher.prototype = ...` will work.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new instance with your constructor, e.g.

```
  const teacher = new Teacher();
```

then JS does the following under the hood:

1) It creates a new object that inherits the constructors `prototype` property

2) It calls the constructor with `this` being the new object:

```
 const teacher = Object.create(Teacher.prototype); // 1
 Teacher.call(teacher); // 2
```

Now if you want the teacher to inherit all methods and properties of Person, you have to make `Teacher.prototype` inherit `Person.prototype` as the instances inherit that. So this:

```
  teacher  -> Teacher.prototype
  teacher2 ->
```

has to be changed to

```
 teacher  -> Teacher.prototype -> Person.prototype
 teacher2 ->
```

therefore the teachers prototype has to inherit the persons prototype.

```
 Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

The other line however:

```
  Teacher = Object.create(Person);
```

Makes little sense as that destroys the Teacher constructor, as `Object.create` returns an object and not a function. You could however:

```
 Object.setPrototypeOf(Teacher, /*to*/ Person);
```

Then `Teacher` would inherit all *static* properties of `Person`, but the instances wouldn't inherit anything, as `Teacher.prototype` does not inherit `Person.prototype`.

Comment: So basically what I was doing was to create an object and not a constructor and what MDN article was doing is to create a constructor to further create instances?

Comment: @himanshu no they created a prototype that inherits another prototype.

Comment: @JonasWilms But why does its prototype link point to nothing?

Comment: @bergi cause I'm bad at ASCIIart and therefore unable to create a right up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
Teacher = Object.create(Person);
```

by the above line of code you are assigning a totally different value to Teacher.

Instead, you could have asked a question about the following:

```
Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype
```

but in this case also, the problem is, any change to Teacher prototype will also change the Person prototype (because they refer the same object), and that could have undesirable side-effects.

So,

```
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

is correct

Comment: I got what you said but what I want to ask is if i create a new obj by Teacher = Object.create(Person) instead of Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype) what will be the difference.?